# Youtubedl --audio-format FORMAT is ignored to download opus audio. Could not write header for output file #0 error

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

> youtube-dl --list-formats
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BDq_22PfWU&t=628s [youtube]
>   4BDq_22PfWU: Downloading webpage [youtube] 4BDq_22PfWU: Downloading
>   video info webpage [info] Available formats for 4BDq_22PfWU: format
>   code  extension  resolution note 249          webm       audio only
>   tiny   51k , opus @ 50k (48000Hz), 31.25MiB 250          webm
>   audio only tiny   81k , opus @ 70k (48000Hz), 44.20MiB 251
>   webm       audio only tiny  133k , opus @160k (48000Hz), 74.26MiB 140 
>   m4a        audio only tiny  135k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k
>   (44100Hz), 87.77MiB 278          webm       256x144    144p   96k ,
>   webm container, vp9, 30fps, video only, 47.91MiB 160          mp4
>   256x144    144p  113k , avc1.4d400c, 30fps, video only, 40.44MiB 242
>   webm       426x240    240p  211k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 69.92MiB
>   133          mp4        426x240    240p  256k , avc1.4d4015, 30fps,
>   video only, 94.52MiB 243          webm       640x360    360p  379k ,
>   vp9, 30fps, video only, 131.62MiB 134          mp4        640x360
>   360p  502k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only, 183.92MiB 244
>   webm       854x480    480p  680k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 213.12MiB
>   135          mp4        854x480    480p  898k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps,
>   video only, 333.53MiB 247          webm       1280x720   720p 1255k ,
>   vp9, 30fps, video only, 436.30MiB 136          mp4        1280x720
>   720p 1810k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 686.32MiB 248
>   webm       1920x1080  1080p 2250k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 712.87MiB
>   137          mp4        1920x1080  1080p 3311k , avc1.640028, 30fps,
>   video only, 1.29GiB 43           webm       640x360    360p , vp8.0,
>   vorbis@128k, 400.22MiB 18           mp4        640x360    360p  393k ,
>   avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2@ 96k (44100Hz), 266.68MiB 22           mp4
>   1280x720   720p 1140k , avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2@192k (44100Hz) (best)

I want to extract best OPUS based audio from Youtube.
For that i'm using:

```
--no-check-certificate --prefer-insecure --audio-format opus --extract-audio --postprocessor-args "-acodec libopus -b:a 64K" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M"
```

It does work sometimes when you have *m4a* container as "best" audio stream, does work if you manually specify *-format 251* which is overkill.
It doesn't work with for *m4a_dash* container as best possible audio stream.
I'm assuming because there is no way to demux opus from *m4a_dash*. Reported as bug due to switch *--audio-format* opus which will force youtubedl to get opus stream(best/worst???)

**ENVIRONMENTS:** Windows 7 x64, ffmpeg version N-71192-g3c91239, youtube-dl.exe
2020.01.01

**OBSERVED RESULT:** will not getting opus stream even with --audio-format opus
Could not write header for output file #0 - error pops up.

**EXPECTED RESULT:** will get opus stream.

Comment: solved, -f bestaudio[ext=webm] - will get best opus stream